# C/C++ editor that can create projects from lists of files

Tags: c++, c, ide

I recently asked a question about i[mporting from a list of source/header files in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939198/importing-list-of-source-files-into-an-eclipse-project)

I haven't found a good solution to this, so I thought I'd check out other IDEs. I want an IDE that does not need to "own" everything from a top directory and down. When creating a new project I want to have a text file that lists source/header files (autogenerated by the build tool), and have the IDE create a project with those files. The only IDE I know of that does this is SlickEdit, which is great, but also rather expensive. Do you know of any other IDEs that have this feature.

Eclipse wants to own everything in the directory I pointed it to, and I haven't found a way to remove subfolders afterwards (to exclude them from search, indexing and annoying me).

Comment: What about creating a Makefile out of the files you want and importing that? Should work with a couple of different editors. Of course you could use the same technique with any project types as well (Eclipse included) if you can figure out the format of the project file.

Comment: I use scons for my build system, which don't integrate well with Eclipse. After looking some more in the prefs for Eclipse I found out that a folder that's excluded from the build can also be excluded from the indexing, and that takes away most of my annoyances. I can live with a bit too many files in the project view.

Answer (score 2):

I think [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs does all this, and more.  The `desktop` feature lets you store a set of files to load and save in a working directory, and the [`Emacs Code Browser (ECB)` extension](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?action=browse;oldid=EmacsClassBrowser;id=EmacsCodeBrowser) has support for browsing files and classes, and managing projects.  It doesn't own anything, Emacs just gives you lots of tools to manipulate text in godly ways.  Along with ECB, `SpeedBar` and a few other extensions, `CEDET` is an Emacs "meta"-extension which turns the venerable editor into an IDE.  It even does UML!

- [Emacs IDE: `CEDET`](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'm a long time emacs user, but I haven't tried the IDE-features much, but I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) can do this for you.